# Implementing an iterator for an arraylist

Tags: java, iterator

I have a list of instance `DynamicArray` which is pretty much an arraylist, 
and here I'm trying to implement an iterator:

The problem is I'm not allowed to add any fields so no index field... and I'm trying to write the method `next()` for my iterator to return the next prime number, and I thought maybe it'd be a good idea to add it to the array as well.

But every time I'd call next it'll set num to 2 and then it won't increment so ultimately it'll only return 2..

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class PrimeIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {

private List<Integer> primes;


//Complete the following method
public PrimeIterator(){

    this.primes = new DynamicArray<Integer>();



}

//Complete the following method
public boolean hasNext(){

    return false;
}

//Complete the following method
public Integer next(){

  Integer num = new Integer(2);

  while(!isPrime(num)){
      num++;
  }
  primes.add(num);
   return num;

}

public boolean isPrime (Integer num){

    for(int i = 2; i*i<=num; i++){

        if(num%i == 0) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

//DO NOT REMOVE OR CHANGE THIS MEHTOD – IT IS REQUIRED 
public void remove() {
    return;
}


}
```

Is there any way to fix this? or any idea of how to use the field I got to do that?

Comment: Which part is your homework and which part did you write?

Comment: I added the isPrime method , and I did write the next method but obviously it doesn't  work properly.. My homework is to implement this iterator for this list of primes. However , next() should only return one prime number at a time, and I should do that using the primes field.. so it's not really like iterating over an array.

Comment: are you allowed to access values that are already stored within the list?

Comment: Yes the only prohibition is adding fields

Comment: Do you mean that you're not allowed to add fields *to the `DynamicArray`* or *to the iterator*?

Comment: I'm not allowed to add fields to the iterator, the dynamicArray is a given class just to use in the implementation of this iterator

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the question the main issue is with the initialization of the incrementing value, which is reset to 2 on every call of `next()`.

To solve such an issue you could access the last entry of the list by simply calling `primes.get(primes.size() - 1)`. Of course this could cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if it is empty so you have to do a little check before like:

```
Integer num = primes.isEmpty() ? Integer.valueOf( 1 ) : primes.get( primes.size() - 1 );
num++;
```

Also note that the returned number should be the last prime number so we have to increment it once before following the rest of the routine. Otherwise the same value would be returned and you would've gained absolutely nothing.

In fact we could easily resolve the problem of increment once by converting the while-loop into a do-while-loop:

```
public Integer next()
{
  int num = primes.isEmpty() ? 1 : primes.get( primes.size() - 1 ).intValue();

  do
  {
    num++;
  }
  while ( !isPrime( num ) );

  Integer primer = Integer.valueOf( num );
  primes.add( primer);
  return primer;
}
```

Comment: what does int num = primes.isEmpty() ? 1 : primes.get( primes.size() - 1 ).intValue(); mean? can you write it in a more old fashioned way?

Comment: it's a conditional expression (well-know as ternary operator) and is like a very short form for if() { }else{ }. If the condition infront of the `?` is true then the left expression ( 1 in this case ) will be assigned to the variable. If not the left expression is assigned. In short this particular line assigns either the last item from the list to the number or 1 if the list is empty and no prime numbers have been added yet.